How to resolve VSCode remote ssh connection error?
I'm facing an issue trying to remote connect to a host with VSCode.
[14:05:22.653] Log Level: 2
[14:05:22.674] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+fake-name", attempt 1
[14:05:22.675] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[14:05:22.675] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[14:05:22.675] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"fake-name":"linux"}
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\config
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[14:05:22.676] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:05:22.677] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[14:05:22.677] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[14:05:22.678] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[14:05:22.678] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[14:05:22.678] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[14:05:22.679] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[14:05:22.697] VS Code version: 1.91.1
[14:05:22.697] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.112.0
[14:05:22.697] win32 x64
[14:05:22.713] SSH Resolver called for host: fake-name
[14:05:22.713] Setting up SSH remote "fake-name"
[14:05:22.727] Using commit id "f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729" and quality "stable" for server
[14:05:22.732] Install and start server if needed
[14:05:22.742] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[14:05:23.044] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.2p1, 
[14:05:23.047] > LibreSSL 3.7.2

[14:05:23.059] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\config"
[14:05:23.059] Running script with connection command: "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 63918 -F "C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\config" "fake-name" bash
[14:05:23.065] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:05:24.268] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:05:24.269] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[14:05:25.585] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[14:05:26.956] "install" terminal command done
[14:05:26.957] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exeThe process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[14:05:26.957] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exeThe process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[14:05:26.968] Resolver error: Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe

Instead of:
[14:05:24.269] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[14:05:25.585] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

I'm expecting something like this:
[13:26:39.641] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[13:26:40.938] > 0c830e778589: running
[13:26:41.060] > Installing to /home/admin/.vscode-server...
[13:26:41.251] > 0c830e778589%%1%%    

I can connect to other remote hosts (I deleted them from remotePlatform line b/c their names seemed irrelevant, there are linux type hosts as well)
I tried executing "C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 63918 -F "C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\config" "fake-name" bash in a cmd prompt, didn't get any errors.
I did check my known_hosts file the port this host is to be connected to on is not in it.
Also, I have some lines in my ssh config file to prevent known_hosts entries:
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile NUL

